# NodeJS TCP Server, onData small chunks

Tags: java, node.js, networking, tcp

I made a simple NodeJS TCP server which a Java Client sends an image:

```
encodedImage = <a base64 encoded image>
out.write("IMG;" + encodedImage);
out.flush();
```

My NodeJS server is as follows:

```
net.createServer(function(TCPSocket){
        TCPSocket.on("data", function(data){
            console.log("TCP Recieved: " + data.length);    
        });
}).listen(5000);
```

However, even if I send all data and flush it immediately, the output is as follows:

```
TCP Recieved: 13
TCP Recieved: 1344
TCP Recieved: 1344
TCP Recieved: 1344
TCP Recieved: 1344
TCP Recieved: 1344
TCP Recieved: 1472
TCP Recieved: 1344
TCP Recieved: 1344
TCP Recieved: 1344
TCP Recieved: 1344
```

I want it to recieve it in a simple chunk, but I assume it is happenng due to NodeJS's event handling mechanism, what is the best way to achieve single chunk of data for data sent as a single chunk? As far as I know, a TCP window can be much larger than 1344 bytes of data. I thought of using header values as  HTTP so I know the length ad construct the object I want.

Comment: This is the way tcp works. Not only in node, but everywhere. You can't control this. And you should not attempt. When writing tcp server, always assume data coming in with random sized chunks.

Comment: Yes, I am aware TCP is a streaming protocol, but I was asking to know if there is a way to trigger the event when specific amount of data was recieved, like java's socket reading, but I need to make a a buffering mechanism

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct, in Node the data will come in chunked.  You'll need to keep a buffer, concatenating all the blocks that come in and then when the socket is closed, write your data out to the file system.  Here is an example that was able to receive an image:

```
net = require('net');
fs = require('fs');

net.createServer(function(socket){
  var buffer = new Buffer(0, 'binary');

  socket.on("data", function(data){
    buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, new Buffer(data,'binary')]);
  });

  socket.on("end", function(data) {
    fs.writeFile("image.jpg", buffer, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Socket[" + socket.name + "] closed, wrote data out to sinfo.data");
      }
    }); 

  });

}).listen(5000);

console.log('ready');
```

I sent an image to it using [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat):

```
$ netcat localhost 5000 < input.jpg
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write the chunks to disk as you receive them?  It's wasteful to buffer the entire image in memory and then write it to disk.

Comment: @josh3736: Your comment is exactly what i am trying. 
I send a base64 encoded socket stream from a client to the server. The server should write an image file from the incoming chunks.
Do you know how to properly write these chunks into the writestream to save ram? 
This is my question: stackoverflow.com/questions/22214267/write-base64-chunks-into-writestream

Comment: Am I missing something? Can't you just use pipe? 
socket.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath));

Comment: I didn't know about socket.pipe() when I wrote this - you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Instead of concatenating buffers do `var list = []; list.push(buffer); .... var final_buffer = Buffer.concat(list);`.

Comment: If i receive continually the buffer from tcp (with some images), how i know that it would finished ? is there a way to do it without the end event ?