# How to inform a NodeJS server of something using PHP?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'd like to add a live functionality to a PHP based forum - new posts would be automatically shown to users as soon as they are created.

What I find a bit confusing is the interaction between the PHP code and NodeJS+socket.io.

How would I go about informing the NodeJS server about new posts and have the server inform the clients that are watching the thread in which the post was posted?

**Edit**

Tried the following code, and it seems to work, my only question is whether this is considered a good solution, as it looks kind of messy to me.

I use socket.io to listen on port 81 to clients, and the server running om port 82 is only intended to be used by the forum - when a new post is created, a PHP script sends a POST request to localhost on port 82, along with the data.

Is this ok?

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(81);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('init', function(threadid) {
        socket.join(threadid);
    });
});

var forumserver = require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (res.socket.remoteAddress == '127.0.0.1' && req.method == 'POST') {
        req.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data = JSON.parse(chunk.toString());
            io.sockets.in(data.threadid).emit('new-post', data.content);
        });
    }

    res.end();
}).listen(82);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution of a HTTP server running on a special port is exactly the solution I ended up with when faced with a similar problem.  The PHP app simply uses [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) to `POST` to the Node server, which then pushes a message out to socket.io.

**However**, your HTTP server implementation is broken.  The `data` event is a [`Stream`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) event; Streams **do not emit messages**, they emit chunks of data.  In other words, the request entity data may be split up and emitted in two chunks.

If the `data` event emitted a partial chunk of data, `JSON.parse` would almost assuredly throw an exception, and your Node server would crash.

You either need to manually [buffer data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14540576/201952), or (my recommendation) use a more robust framework for your HTTP server like [Express](http://expressjs.com):

```
var express = require('express'), forumserver = express();
forumserver.use(express.bodyParser()); // handles buffering and parsing of the
                                       // request entity for you
forumserver.post('/post/:threadid', function(req, res) {
    io.sockets.in(req.params.threadid).emit('new-post', req.body.content);
    res.send(204); // HTTP 204 No Content (empty response)
});

forumserver.listen(82);
```

PHP simply needs to post to http​://localhost:82/post/1234 with an entity body containing `content`.  (JSON, URL-encoded, or multipart-encoded entities are acceptable.)  Make sure your firewall blocks port 82 on your public interface.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Should I have the two servers in the same file, or should I split them up into two files, and consequently two instances of node.js?

Comment: You'll want one instance of Node, but that doesn't mean you have to have everyhing in a single file.  In your main app.js, `require('./forumserver.js')(io);`.  Move the forum server stuff to that file, and wrap it with `exports=module.exports=function(io) { ... }`

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you, but I've come into another issue. Each forum post has various things that are based on user permissions, such as the ability to delete posts, approve posts, moderate posts and view the poster's IP address. I can serve the Node server a few versions of each post, however, I need to determine each client's permissions, and this is where I'm having some trouble. How would you suggest to handle this?

Comment: @Lior: That dives pretty deep into the internals of your PHP app, and I doubt there's an easy answer unfortunately.

Comment: So just in general, performance-wise, would I better fetch the permissions using Node.js (which means connecting to the forum database) or request the permissions from PHP after PHP serves a new post to the Node server?

Comment: What I would probably do is just include the anonymous version of the post in the socket.io message.  Then when the browser receives the new post notification, if the user is logged in, fetch that user's version of the post directly from PHP.

Comment: That's actually a good idea, it wouldn't make the slightest difference performance-wise. Thanks again for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the PHP code / forum's interaction with Node.JS, you probably need to create an API endpoint of sorts that can listen for changes made to the forum. Depending on your forum software, you would want to hook into the process of creating a new post and perform the API callback to Node.js at this time.

Socket.io out of the box is geared towards visitors of the site being connected on the frontend via Javascript. Upon the Node server receiving notification of a new post update, it would then notify connected clients of this new post and its details, at which point it would probably add new HTML to the DOM of the page the visitor is viewing.

You may want to arrange the Socket.io part of things so that users only subscribe to specific events being emitted by them being in a specific room such as "subforum123" so that they only receive notifications of applicable posts.

Comment: Thanks, my question is how do I actually perform the API callback to Node.js? One idea I have is to use an event that would be used only by the forum software (the Node.js server would make sure the IP of the client is the same as the forum's IP) and then do a broadcast. I guess it's kind of messy though, and I'm sure there is a neater way to accomplish that.