# node.js net module pings and messages not happening

Tags: node.js, tcpserver, qtcpsocket

I have two node.js applications running side by side on my server and I wan't to send server-side messages between them in a light weight manner using native node.js (v0.10.33) module net

I intend the first application to send messages to the second. I see the console log `listening...`,

In the first application:

```
var push='';
var net=require('net');
var server=net.createServer(function(p){
    p.on('error',function(err){console.log(err);});
    push=p;
    setInterval(function(){push.write(JSON.stringify({'f':'ping','data':'stay alive'}));},1000);
    });
server.listen(8008,function(){console.log('listening...')});

//a real message might be sent later in the application (this example would need a setTimeout)
push.write(JSON.stringify({'f':'msg','data':'Hello World'}));
```

In the second application I see the console log `open`

```
var net=require('net');
var pull=new net.Socket();
pull.connect(8008,'127.0.0.1',function(){console.log('open');
pull.on('data',function(_){
    _=JSON.parse(_);
    if(_.f==='ping'){console.log('!!!ping!!!');}
    else{console.log(_.data);}
    });
pull.on('error',function(err){console.log('pull: '+err);});
});
```

I do not see any other activity though (no pings, and later after the open event, no hello world) and no errors.

If I inspect with `console.dir(pull)` I don't see events for accepting data ie: ondata or onmessage

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I must point out that this messaging scheme is fundamentally broken.  You're using TCP, [which provides a stream of bytes, not messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14540576/201952).

> Despite the fact that TCP sends its data over IP packets, TCP is **not** a packet protocol.  A TCP socket is simply a *stream* of data.  Thus, it is incorrect to view the `data` event as a logical *message*.  In other words, one `socket.write` on one end does not equate to a single `data` event on the other.  A single `data` event might contain *multiple* messages, a single message, or only part of a message.

The good news is this is a problem already solved many times over.  I'd recommend either:

- Using [a library](https://www.google.com/search?q=node%20tcp%20json) meant for passing JSON messages over TCP.
- Using something like redis as a pub-sub messaging solution (this option makes your app much easier to scale)
- If you know that your two apps will always run on the same machine, you should use node's [built-in IPC mechanism](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle).