# How to make a node.js application keep listening after closing a socket?

Tags: node.js, sockets, loops

I'm trying to set up a node.js application that could receive connections and still be listening to port 9001 once a socket is ended. How can I do that? Here is my current code (it doesn't close after the socket.end(), but it won't accept any other connections) :

```
var net = require('net');
var mySocket;

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    mySocket = socket;
    mySocket.on("connect", onConnect);
    mySocket.on("data", onData);
});

function onConnect() {
    console.log("Connected");
}

function onData(command) {
    if (command == "exit") {
        console.log("Exiting");
        mySocket.end();
    }
}

console.log("Waiting for incoming connections");
server.listen(9001);
```

I tried to add another `server.listen(9001);` after the `socket.end();`, but I get a : `Error: listen EADDRINUSE` message.
Also, will that code be able to receive several connections coming from different addresses at the same time, and handle them separately?

This is the full code. When executed, node.js receives 4 commands from the Flash application, and works properly (except that the onConnect() function seems never to be called), and the "exit;" command closes the socket properly, yet if I reload the Flash application, it doesn't connect to the server

```
var net = require('net');
const PACKET_SEPARATOR = 59 // ;
var connection_ack = false;
var counter = 0;

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    function onConnect() {
        console.log("Connected to Flash");
    }

    function dataHandler(command) {
        if (command[command.length - 1] != String.fromCharCode(PACKET_SEPARATOR) && connection_ack) {
       console.log("SEP : " + PACKET_SEPARATOR + " - last : " + command[command.length - 1] + " - ack " + connection_ack);
            console.log("CAUGHT EXCEPTION : WRONG PACKET FORMAT --- " + command + " --- " + command.length);
        }
        if (command == "exit;") {
            console.log("Received exit request from " + socket.address().address + ":" + socket.address().port + " (" + socket.address().family + "). Ending connection...");
            socket.end();
        }
        else if (command == "<policy-file-request/>\0") {
            socket.write('<cross-domain-policy>\n<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />\n</cross-domain-policy>\0', 'utf8');
            console.log("Policy file sent to " + socket.address().address + ":" + socket.address().port);
            player1.pxacceleration = 0;
            player1.pyacceleration = 0;
            connection_ack = true;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Got data from " + socket.address().address + ":" + socket.address().port + " (" + socket.address().family + ")");
            console.log("--> " + command);
            counter++;
            socket.write("Received " + counter + " commands;", 'utf8');
            console.log("Sending : Received " + counter + " commands;");
        }
    }

    function onData(d) {
        var command = "";
        for (i=0; i <= d.length - 1; i++) {
            command += String.fromCharCode(d[i]);
            if (d[i] == PACKET_SEPARATOR || i == d.length - 1 && !connection_ack) {
                dataHandler(command);
                command = "";
            }
        }
    }

    socket.on("connect", onConnect);
    socket.on("data", onData);
});

console.log("Ready. Waiting for incoming connections");
server.listen(9001);
server.listen(80); //TODO : Remove?
```

Comment: Unless you close `server` what you want should already be happening.

Comment: The `server` should already out-live the individual `socket`s. For multiple clients, the `server` will create multiple `socket`s that can be open and active at the same time. The global `mySocket`, on the other hand, will not help the `server` properly support multiple clients as it can only store 1 of them.

Comment: Very bad to use `mySocket` as a global.  As soon as you have more than one socket connecting at once, your `mySocket` variable is overwritten.  Make onData be a local function and you can directly reference `socket` without using a global.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you provide me a small example?

Comment: [TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol.  A `data` event does **not** necessarily equate to a single write.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14540576/201952)

Comment: I know, that's why I added the instructions in `onData` to split the packets into several messages. This is only temporary since my program will mostly use streams to communicate.

Comment: You're not buffering correctly though.  `command` is a local in the data handler, meaning it is empty every time the `data` event fires.  Consider what happens when a message (ie `ABCDEF`) is split: packet 1 will have `ABC`, packet 2 will have `DEF`.  You've lost the ABC part of the message.

Comment: Also, don't manually convert buffers to strings.  [Set the socket's encoding](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_setencoding_encoding) to `utf8` (or whatever encoding you're actually expecting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jfriend00 said, using `mySocket` as a global is not recommended. Try the below instead.

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    function onData(command) {
        if (command == "exit") {
            console.log("Exiting");
            socket.end();
        }
    }
    socket.on("connect", onConnect);
    socket.on("data", onData);
});
...
```

This eliminates the need for the global in the first place. This should also allow multiple sockets and prevent the original error. I think. I'm new here, so I guess we will see.

**EDIT**
Alright. I've been interacting with your code via telnet. I've also read up on some of the documentation. First, the `socket.on("connect", onConnect);` listener should be moved(along with the `onConnect` function) into the global scope and changed to `server.on("connection", onConnect);`. The reason for this is that the socket event listener `connect` is a client side listener. We are working  server side. The server side listener for new connections is `connection` and the server should be listening for it in the same way it is listening for connections on a particular port.

This part of your code should look like this now:

```
//more code up above here
....
    function onData(d) {
        var command = "";
        for (i=0; i <= d.length - 1; i++) {
            command += String.fromCharCode(d[i]);
            if (d[i] == PACKET_SEPARATOR || i == d.length - 1 && !connection_ack) {    
                dataHandler(command);
                command = "";
            }
        }
    }
    socket.on("data", onData);
});

function onConnect() {
    console.log("Connected to Flash");
}

server.on("connection", onConnect);
....
//more code below here
```

However, the code would not recognize `exit` as a command via telnet. I was unable to figure this bit out. Since your question did not cover this problem it might just be me or you have it figured out.

**EDIT 2**
The code below keeps it local.

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    function onConnect() {
        console.log("Connected to Flash");
        socket.write("we're connected");
    }
....
    function onData(d) {
        var command = "";
        for (i=0; i <= d.length - 1; i++) {
            command += String.fromCharCode(d[i]);
            if (d[i] == PACKET_SEPARATOR || i == d.length - 1 && !connection_ack) {    
                dataHandler(command);
                command = "";
            }
        }
    }
    onConnect();
    socket.on("data", onData);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I implemented your solution, but it's still not working. I updated my question with the full code

Comment: Thanks! Though, I can't define `onConnect()` in the global scope since the socket is only defined inside the `net.createServer(function(socket){...})`. How could I solve that?
Also, the "exit;" command is only a string that I send using Flash. It could have been "quit;" or anything else, it's just the syntax that my Actionscript program uses for now

Comment: You could just leave the `onConnect` function in the local scope and then just use `onConnect();` without the listener since it only would get called every time there is a new socket connection to the server anyway. I will edit accordingly so it's clear.

Comment: It's almost working now, and I get the "Connected to Flash" message each time. The only issue left is that the `onData()` listener is not recreated after the first socket is ended (the server does not react to any data sent from Flash except while the first socket is active).

Comment: I've been able to close and reopen multiple sockets via telnet. I cannot replicate your error. Try using `socket.destroy();` instead of `socket.end();` and see where that gets you. This completely destroys the socket and is usually only used for troubleshooting.

Comment: It doesn't work, but this time the problem probably comes from the client side. I'll try to fix that on my own, thanks for the help.